# Let M be the DFA with state diagram

Tags: computer-science

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoXru.png

a) Construct the transition table of M
b) which of the strings baba,baab,abab,abaaab
c) Give a regular expression for L(M)

I actually missed class the day that this was covered due to illness, and i'm confused greatly by this. I've checked wikipedia for info on DFA, but it made me even more confused. ANY insight on this topic as it pertains to this problem would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: have you tried asking your processor, TA, or peers in the class?

Comment: might be more suited for http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

DFA = Deterministic Finite-State Automata (search),

- There is a start state (see `q0`, with the `>` beside it),
- (zero or more) non-terminal states designated by circles (see the names inside),
- the terminal (ending) state designate by double concentric circles,
- state transitions designated by the lines (arrows), which are labeled by events

A DFA (DFSA) can be used to 'recognize' patterns of input.  You feed an input pattern (a string of characters) to the DFA, and as the DFA transitions between states, it either recognizes the next entry, or produces error/unrecognized result.  When the input is finished, you check whether the ending state is a terminal/recognized state.

Implemented as follows:

```
states[] = { 'q0', 'q1', 'q2' }
events[] = { 'a', 'b' }
transition[]
transition['q0'] = []
transition['q1'] = []
transition['q2'] = []
transition['q0']['a'] = 'q1'
transition['q0']['b'] = 'q0'
transition['q1']['a'] = 'q1
transition['q1']['b'] = 'q2'
transition['q2']['a'] = 'q0'
transition['q2']['b'] = 'q1'
state = 'q0' #start state
terminal[]
terminal['q2'] = true # you can have more than one terminal/recognized state
terminal['q0'] = false # you can have more than one terminal/recognized state
terminal['q1'] = false # you can have more than one terminal/recognized state
```

You could implement the above state machine as, (rubylike)
    terminal['q2'] = 1 # you can have more than one terminal/recognized state

```
def DFArun( initstate, input )
    state = initstate
    each input.each do |inp|
        if !transition[ state, inp ].exists then
            return :notrecognized
        end
        state = transition [ state, inp ]
    end
    if terminal[ state ].exists then return :recognized
    else return :notrecognized end
end
```

You can further annotate a DFSA or DFSM (Deterministic Finite State Machine) with semantic actions that occur when certain transitions are made.  This can be to 'emit' output on certain transitions ('recognized'), or to cause certain actions to occur.  A DFA (DFSA, DFSM) can be used to recognize tokens in a language parser, or to control factory automation, or business workflow.

You can easily express the recognition of a DFSM in a file which can be loaded into a DFSM for operation, and thereby build a program which has its actions controlled by an editable file.  For example, a simple CSV file,

```
#state,input,newstate,actions(optional)
q0,a,q1,none
q0,b,q0,none
q1,a,q1,none
q1,b,q2,none
q2,a,q0,none
q2,b,q1,none
init,q0
terminal,q2
```